# How install the last version of Remmina on Raspbian Stretch?

Tags: raspbian, rdp

How can I install the last version of Remmina on Raspbian Stretch 9.1? I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2

Comment: What is the latest version number? Is the Raspberry Pi a supported platform? Is it available via apt? Since the Pi is debian based have you tried this https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki/Compile-on-Debian-9-Stretch?

Comment: It is available in apt have you tried installing it via sudo apt install remmina?

Comment: Hello, yes, I try the Compile On Debian 9 Stretch. But I don't know why he doesn't work. Some commands don't work. But I'm not try with sudo apt-get install remmina. But If try with this command is it the last version who'll is installed ?

Comment: I don't know try it and see

Comment: Alright, I will try it... :)

Comment: It's work! (#sudo apt-get install remina remina-plugin-rdp). And I have the last release. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For install Remmina on your Raspberry Pi 3, make the command :

## sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp

That all...

Enjoy